# Deploying multiple modules using 'gcloud preview app deploy'

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I currently have an app containing two modules, each with its own version number. When I run 'gcloud preview app deploy module1/app.yaml module2/app.yaml' I get the following error:

> One or more files have conflicting settings for the [version] field.

If these version numbers need to be the same, is there a way to separately version your modules or is this not supported?

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like I should not be naming my module configuration files 'app.yaml' (a reserved name). By naming the files 'module1.yaml' and 'module2.yaml' the problem was resolved.

Comment: RIght.  There's only one app, thus only one `app.yaml` -- but as many modules as you wish:-).

Comment: Thanks makes sense. Part of the confusion was that I did not receive that error when deploying using the appcfg tool.